# How to run Microsoft Store programs in MaxLauncher program?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, microsoft-store

This is a MaxLaucher review video:
youtube.com/watch?v=0MdruOzAJ1M

What to type in the target textbox for Microsoft Store programs that have no path to an executable file, if I want Alarms & Clock program to open, what about "Telegram Desktop", I imagine it would be something like putting in the target textbox: "alarm" and for "telegram" because these programs don't have an .exe path as I think. Also how to run Microsoft store (I guess it would be something like typing in the target textbox: "msstore" or something.), how to run recycle bin and how "My Computer" Folder? I would like it if you link me to a page with all of these programs as simple commands as I saw a page with a difficult way to find the commands...

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. How to run "Apps" is complicated enough. // Requests for learning material are off-topic.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you mean, I'm asking only what to type in the "target" textbox in the said program to run Microsoft Store apps since I can't find a path for an exe for any of them...

Comment: First you should read their [documentation](https://maxlauncher.sourceforge.io/), then you should tell us what you are trying to do and ask a question detailing where your problem is. This isn't a site for giving tutorials on how to use entire programs or packages from start to finish, it is a problem solving Question and Answer site.

Comment: Thx a lot, this seems to have solved it:
maxlauncher.sourceforge.io/documentation/kb/32/

Comment: @John1 it would probably be good to post an answer stating how to do it. Rather than just a link though it would be good to say "You cannot directly do it, but you can go here and create a shortcut that Maxlauncher can use..."

Answer (score 0):

You can open Windows 10 apps folder, create shortcuts for the apps on the desktop, copy each and paste it in the desired button of MaxLauncher, you can delete the shortcuts later, as described here:

maxlauncher.sourceforge.io/documentation/kb/32/